# why the gtag event doesn't appear in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, gtag.js

my script like this :

```
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxxx-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1');

      console.log('test');
      console.log(gtag('event', 'Click', { 'event_category': 'Outbound Link', 'event_action':'Click','event_label':'Live365BroadcastLaunch-ListenLive' }));
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    ...
    <a onclick="gtag('event', 'Click', { 'event_category': 'Outbound Link', 'event_action':'Click','event_label':'Live365BroadcastLaunch-ListenLive' });" class="test" href="...">
        <div class="text">test</div>
    </a>
    ...
</body>

</html>
```

The console.log of `console.log(gtag('event', 'Click', { 'event_category': 'Outbound Link', 'event_action':'Click','event_label':'Live365BroadcastLaunch-ListenLive' }));
    </script>` is `undefined`

after I clicked on the test button, I tried to check on google analytics. the result like this :

[image]

there are seen total events = 0

how could this happen? Is the code writing process wrong?

Comment: where is ur code right now ? on local or server ?

Comment: In the real-time report you did not see any event-type interaction after you clicked on the test button?

Comment: @sayalok my code on the server

Comment: @MichelePisani Yes. I did not see any event-type

Comment: "event_action" parameter is not expected. Try to remove it: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the real-time reports, for other views, the data could take up to 24-48 hours:
[image]

The code/implementation provided works fine as-is, make sure you don't have any ad/tracking blockers:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

gtag.js event tracking syntax is the following:

```
gtag('event', 'action', {'event_category': 'category', 'event_label': 'label', 'value': value});
```

ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events
event_label and value are optional.
as per @Michele Pisani comment event_action is not a valid parameter

The following should work for your link

```
<a onclick="gtag('event', 'Click', { 'event_category': 'Outbound Link', 'event_label':'Live365BroadcastLaunch-ListenLive' });" class="test" href="...">
```

Sometimes when a link loads a new page in the same browser window, it happens before the event hit can be sent and tracked by GA. In these instances adding target="_blank" to the link can help